# Registering a custom control with bind link association requires unit BindCompRelationships that does not exist

Tags: delphi, package, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I made a simple package (designtime and runtime) that contains this single unit:

```
Unit MECompsBuildTest1Reg;

Interface

Uses
  FMX.Controls;

Type
  TMEImageControl = Class(TStyledControl)
  End;

Procedure Register;

Implementation

Uses
  System.Classes,
  FMX.Bind.DBLinks,
  BindCompFMXReg;

Procedure Register;
Begin
  RegisterComponents('MEComps', [TMEImageControl]);
  TDBBindLinkAssocations.AddAssociations([TBindDBImageLink], [TMEImageControl]);
End;

End.
```

This package requires:

- rtl.dcp
- DesignIDE.dcp

Strangely it does not require fmx.dcp (I wonder why, since I am referencing FMX.Controls.TStyledControl).

But this package does not compile:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] BindCompEdit.pas(19): F2613 Unit
> 'BindCompRelationships' not found.

**This unit is nowhere to be found in the Delphi installation. There is no source file, no dcu file. I have tried requiring all of the available dcps and the unit is still not found.**

This is not the same problem as the [one I've posted weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42413376/developing-new-teditbutton-types-requires-dclfmxstd-package-which-does-not-exist). In that case the referenced standard Delphi unit exists but resides in a BPL and not in a DCP that I can require. In this case the standard Delphi unit does not exist (as source) and does not seem to reside anywhere in the Delphi installation (but I may be wrong OC).

I have reported this [issue on the Embarcadero (QP RSP-17685)](https://quality.embarcadero.com/login.jsp?permissionViolation=true&os_destination=/browse/RSP-17685&page_caps=&user_role=)

Comment: It is similar, as i myself have noted, but I don't see how it is an exact duplicate. And since the other one has no answer or comment, maybe exposing a slightly different problem in a different way can help us find a solution. Thinks could be cleaned up after we have a good answer. Just my two cents.

Comment: Can't you do that at the other question.

Comment: If the non-virtual functions are not private you may still be able to descend from TEditButton provided you don't need the virtual aspect, which is to say provided you don't assign your TLinkControlToField to a TEditButton variable or an array/list of TEditButton and then try to use non-virtual functions from that variable/list. Not an answer but something to consider.

Comment: No... those methods are public. But the problem here is not how to implement the component... but how to get this package to build correctly.